# Conflict with RxPermission

Tags: gradle, rxpermissions

I want to use the[tbruyelle
RxPermissions](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) library  in my project. I can not call the `subcribe` method like here

```
rxPermissions
    .request(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    .subscribe(granted -> {
        if (granted) {
           
        } else {
           
        }
    });
```

On the method "request" shows the error

```
Cannot access class 'io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

My `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    //For YandexMap
    maven { url "http://maven.google.com/" }
    //For RxPermission
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
// rx - network
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'

// rx
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.20'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.4.0'

//RxPermission
implementation 'com.github.tbruyelle:rxpermissions:0.12'
```

Comment: upgrade to "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0"